# running a thread in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am inside a threat updating a graph and I go into a routine that makes a measurement for 4 seconds.  The routine returns a double.  What I am noticing is that my graph stops showing activity for 4 seconds until I am done collecting data.  I need to start a new thread and put the GetTXPower() activity in the background.  So in other words I want GetTXPower() and the graph charting to run in parallel.  Any suggestions?

here is my code:

```
             stopwatch.Start();
            // Get Tx Power reading and save the Data
            _specAn_y = GetTXPower();
            _pa_Value = paData.Start;
            DataPoint.Measurement = _specAn_y;
            //Thread.Sleep(50);
            double remaining = 0;                
            do
            {
              charting.stuff  
            }
            uxChart.Update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking into [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the TPL is the preferred way to write multithreaded and parallel code.

Since you also need the result back from `GetTXPower`, I would use a `Task<double>` for it.

```
Task<double> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<double>(GetTXPower);
```

Depending on when you need the result, you can query if the task has completed by checking `task.IsCompleted` or alternatively block the thread and wait for the task to finish by calling `task.Wait()`. You can fetch the result through `task.Result` property.

An alternative would be to add a continuation to the initial task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<double>(GetTXPower).ContinueWith(task => 
{
    // Do something with the task result.
});
```

Comment: Great recommendation.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make a void method (I'll call it `MeasureMentMethod`) that collects the data. The create a Thread using the following code:

```
Thread MeasurementThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MeasurementMethod));
```

You can then run the thread with

```
MeasurementThread.Start();
```

And if your Thread has something like this:

```
while(true){
    //Run your code here
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Then you can just start it at the beginning, and it will just keep collecting data.

So, you would have your main thread that would update the chart, and you would start the thread that would get the data on the side.

Comment: @ Patrick vD   Thanks for your suggestion.  My method returns a double so this is not working as expected  public double GetTXPower()

Comment: @Patrick vD   I get an error saying the method returns the wrong type

Comment: @Patrick vD I changed my method type to void and seems to be working now.  I am still working the details.

Comment: @Sophman Ok, sorry didn't see any those messages. My recommendation would be to have a `List<double>` with all of the results. You can just grab the last double with `listName[liastName.Length-1];`. Then have your void just store the value in the List instead of returning a double.